# How can I install pip package persistently on Tails?

Tags: pip, tails

I installed pip3 using following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y python3-pip
```

When I run `pip3 install --user passphraseme`, package is not installed persistently.

How can I install pip package persistently on Tails?